# I'm trying to add poster URLs to my neo4j movie database using JavaScript, but I'm getting this undefined object error all the time

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I'm completely new to JavaScript and having a hard time trying to understand asynchronous calls. Do I need to nest another promise object to set the poster URLs?

```
async function getIds() {
    const result = await session.run("MATCH (m :Movie) RETURN m.imdbId LIMIT 5");
    const ids = [];
    result.records.forEach(record => ids.push(record._fields[0]));
    return ids;
}

async function imdbIds() {
    const ids = await getIds();
    console.log(ids);
    const response = await Promise.all(ids.map(async id => {
        // webscraper that returns poster url of each imdbid
        const url = toString(scraper(id));
        console.log(url);

        // query to set poster of each id in neo4j db
        const result = await session.run("MATCH (m :Movie {imdbId : $id}) SET m.poster = $url RETURN m.poster", { id, url });
        result.records.forEach(record => console.log(record._fields[0]));
        return result;
    }));
    console.log(response);
}

imdbIds();
```

Console logs still no luck:

```
[ '0114709', '0113497', '0113228', '0114885', '0113041' ]
[object Undefined]
[object Undefined]
[object Undefined]
[object Undefined]
[object Undefined]
[object Undefined]
[object Undefined]
[object Undefined]
[object Undefined]
[object Undefined]
[ { records: [ [Record] ],
    summary:
     ResultSummary {
       statement: [Object],
       statementType: 'rw',
       counters: [StatementStatistics],
       updateStatistics: [StatementStatistics],
       plan: false,
       profile: false,
       notifications: [],
       server: [ServerInfo],
       resultConsumedAfter: [Integer],
       resultAvailableAfter: [Integer] } } ...
```

Comment: By the way, you probably mean "scraper" instead of "scrapper".

Comment: yes, pardon my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out, thanks for help mr. ashish modi

```
async function setPosters() {
    const result = await session.run("MATCH (m :Movie) RETURN m.imdbId LIMIT 15");
    result.records.forEach(async record => {
        const imdbId = record._fields[0];
        const url = await scraper(imdbId);
        await session.run("MATCH (m :Movie {imdbId : $imdbId}) SET m.poster = $url RETURN m.poster", { imdbId, url });
    });
}

setPosters();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `getIds` function. you have wrapped a already promise returning function in another promise. second problem is your getIds function. you are doing asynchronous operation in forEach which will not work. Replace it with `Promise.all` it should be like this

```
async function getIds() {
  const result = await session.run("MATCH (m :Movie) RETURN m.imdbId LIMIT 5");
  const ids = [];
  result.records.forEach(record => ids.push(record._fields[0]));
  return ids;
}

async function imdbIds() {
  const ids = await getIds();
  console.log(ids);
  const response = await Promise.all(ids.map(async id => {
    // webscraper that returns poster url of each imdbid
    const url = toString(scraper(id));
    console.log(url);

    // query to set poster of each id in neo4j db
    const result = await session.run("MATCH (m :Movie {imdbId : $id}) SET m.poster = $url RETURN m.poster", {id, url});
    result.records.forEach(record => console.log(record._fields[0]));
    return result;
  }));
  console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: i made some changes to my code which is reflected in the question but im still having undefined object issue

Comment: I have modified it to use async await.

Comment: still the same issue, updated my question with your code and logs

Comment: we were not returning anything from promise.all..updated the code

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: check your query in that case. What is the result coming inside promise.all?

Comment: turns out there was a problem with my scrapper. it works now thanks. can you suggest me a resource for learning about async js.

Comment: Glad it works now. You could look at this link - https://alligator.io/js/async-functions/